# The value in the condition without a variable

Tags: javascript

I hope to get the result and assign it a new value using such a short entry. I want the result and value to be without creating a variable. How should I do it right?

for example:

```
let clientOnline =[{num:4},{num:1},{num:3}];
let myValue =clientOnline.find(cli=>cli['num']===4)
if(myValue) myValue['num'] = 0;
```

What I would like:

```
let clientOnline =[{num:4},{num:1},{num:3}]
if(clientOnline.find(cli=>cli['num']===4)) this['num']=4
```

I have more experience in languages where variables need to be freed. I know that JS does it on its own. But I really want to control it. I hope it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the element in the array and update it in one go

```
clientOnline.map(c => c.num === 4 ? ({ num: "new_value" }) : c)
```

#### Update (addressing your comment)

If you have multiple elements with the same value then you can simply use a `for` loop and stop whenever you need.

```
for(let i = 0; i < clientOnline.length; i++) {
  if(clientOnline[i].num === 4) {
    clientOnline[i].num = "new_value"
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: It works. I ran into a problem when I had several identical values. "map" has done the action for everyone when I need to stop at the first one. I apologize for not specifying this condition right away.

Comment: I've updated the answer, best to use a for loop in this case as you can't break out of `map`

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the answer to my question. It's a pity that it doesn't turn out to be a short entry in one line. Could you give me some advice in my case , which option uses less computer resources ? A loop or a "pointer through a declared variable"?

Comment: I don't really know to be honest, but my guess would be a loop